How to pop up screen keyboard in flutter windows application programmatically
I am developing the kiosk application by using flutter and there is an issue coming out that I can't handle on screen keyboard of windows pop up when textfield focused or something. Is there any way to implement native on screen keyboard without activating tablet mode or something...
I already tried the flutter_virtual_keyboard new_virtual_keyboard and Process.start('osk.exe', []), or much things but it wont work as I expected at all
example code is SizedBox( width: context.width, height: 44, child: TextField( controller: controller.searchbymodelNbrand, // autofocus: true, focusNode: controller.focusNode, textInputAction: TextInputAction.done, keyboardType: TextInputType.text, style: TextStyle( fontFamily: "RobotoRegular", fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: KioskColor.deepblue), decoration: InputDecoration( filled: true, fillColor: const Color(0XFFF2F4F7), prefixIcon: Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10), child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/search-icon.svg"), ), contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, hintText: "${'model_tr'.tr}, ${'brand_tr'.tr} ${'search_tr'.tr.toLowerCase()}", hintStyle: TextStyle( fontFamily: "RobotoMedium", fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 14, color: KioskColor.gray), enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), borderSide: BorderSide.none), focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), borderSide: BorderSide.none), ), onTap: () async { FocusNode().requestFocus(); controller.fieldFocused.value = true; // try { //   Process.start( //       "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\ink\\TabTip.exe", //       []); // } catch (error) { //   print(error); // } }, onEditingComplete: () { controller.getCarFilters(pageNumber: 0, pagesize: 20); }, ), // ), ),

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
